# Querying database with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to query my database using php, to then display the results of the query. For this example, I only want the number of elements in my MySQL database.

My code is:

```
<?php
    print("This is just a test");
    print("This is another test");
    // Create connection
    $con=mysqli_connect("mysql.netsons.com","****","****","****");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    print("A third test");

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyGames");
    echo $result;
    echo mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    print("A forth test");
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is the result:

```
This is just a testThis is another testA third test
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `echo $result;` won't work, because `$result` is an object if your query succeeds and boolean `false` if not. Post the output of this command after your call to `mysqli_query()`: `echo mysqli_error($con);`

Comment: If you want info on a variable that may be an array or Boolean, echo won't work - try var_dump.

Comment: @EdCottrell With that change the fourth print get display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` fetches ... an array.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row["COUNT(*)"];
```

I think it would be better to alias that column too:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM MyGames
...
echo $row['count'];
```

Comment: Okay, this one solved it: $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row["COUNT(*)"]; But I am not sure I completely understand how. So, what exactly contain $row?

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend using a diferent method of querying that is much safer(As far as I know there is no SQL Injection to worry about) and it saves a lot of time and space.

First you need to create an mysqli object

```
$stateConnect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "PASS", "DBTable");
```

This does the same thing as `mysqli_connect` and `mysqli_select_db`
Then you want to define your SQL query

```
$sql = "SELECT `userVotes` FROM `users` WHERE `userEmail`=?";
```

Next you want to create a variable called a statement with your SQL "attached to it"

```
$statement = $stateConnect->prepare($sql);
```

Notice how in my SQL I didn't directly put the value required for userEmail, instead I put an '?'. This acts as a variable that we will later define(However it will always be a '?'

To define this variable we need to use.

```
$statement->bind_param('s', $SESSION['email']);
```

This binds `$SESSION['email']` to the first qustion mark, the `s` is saying that the first question mark will be a string. Lets say we had to varribles:

```
$sql = "SELECT `userVotes` FROM `users` WHERE `userEmail`=? AND `userName`=?";
```

We would then use:

```
$statement->bind_param('ss', $SESSION['email'], "USERNAME");
```

Each s replresents a question mark and each value after that represents a question mark.

Now we have to execute our query with.

```
$statement->execute();
```

If we are expecting a result to be returned then we have to use

```
$statement->bind_result($userVotesText);
```

To bind the results to a variable, If I was expecting to columns of results I would need to put a second variable in.

Now to set those varribles we need to use

```
if($statement->fetch()){
    $userVotesResult = userVotesText;
}
```

This method is much better than other for querying databases and is called [Prepared Statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)